# Term for how close a polygon is to a cirlce

Tags: circles, polygons

I'm pretty sure this exists but I can't find anything when I search for it. Maybe I'm not searching for the right thing.

I believe there is an equation that outputs how close any given polygon is to a circle.

I'm doing calculations that deal with polygons and circles. The method for polygons is much more complex than for a circle. Therefore, if I deem a polygon to be *close enough* to a circle, I'll convert it to one.

Comment: I'm not sure how one would do this, honestly. It depends on how you define closeness I suppose. For some polygons, you could circumscribe and inscribe a circle in them, and compare some certain parameter between them (e.g. their radius), and the closer those parameters are I guess you could say the closer the polygon is to being a circle. This can't be done with all polygons though

Comment: Can you please to quantify "*close enough*"? Is it about the sides of the polygon not going further than $x$ from the circle? Or the circumference of the polygon being at most $x$ shorter than the circumference of the circle? Or the area of the polygon being at most $x$ smaller than the area of the circle? Or something else? All of the above can be expressed mathematically and will give you different measures of being "close enough".

Comment: How about using the [isoperimetric ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_ratio) of a curve. Let $L$ be the perimeter and $A$ be the area enclosed by a nice enough curve. [Isoperimetric inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality) tell us $L^2 \ge 4\pi A$ and equality happens when and only when the curve is a circle. If the isoperimetric ratio $\frac{L^2}{A}$ of a polygon is close enough to $4\pi$, you can consider treating it as a circle.

Comment: @achillehui, yes that's perfect! You should write it as an answer so I can accept it